# Changing multidimensional array's values into a new array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array which was posted from jquery's   `.serializeArray()` method and i got this array through the `$_POST` global variable.

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Name
        [value] => Posted Name
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Contact
        [value] => Posted Number
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => email
        [value] => 
    )
)
```

I need an array which looks like this :

```
Array (
    'Name' => 'Posted Name',
    'Contact name' => 'Posted Number',
    'email' => ''
)
```

Comment: How do you get from `Contact` to `Contact name` ? Have you tried something?

Comment: use a foreach on your `$_POST` and set the `['name']` as the key, and `['value']` as the value in a new array.

Comment: I did foreach ($_POST['data'] as $i) {
  foreach($i as $key => $value){
   //Stuck right here 
  }
 }

Comment: instead of `foreach($i as...`, do `$newArray[$i['name']] = $i['value'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$postArray[0] = array('name' => 'Name', 'value' => 'Posted Name');
$postArray[1] = array('name' => 'Contact', 'value' => 'Posted Number');
$postArray[2] = array('name' => 'email', 'value' => '');

foreach($postArray as $item) {

    if($item['name'] == "Name")
        $newArr['name'] = $item['value'];

    if($item['name'] == "Contact")
        $newArr['Contact name'] = $item['value'];

    if($item['name'] == "email")
        $newArr['email'] = $item['value'];

}

print_r($newArr);
```